# nodejs - optimum number of workers in cluster

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, worker

When clustering nodejs on a multi-core processor [I usually see examples saying](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html) -

```
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
```

My questions are -

1. If a multi-core processor is running a web app with a reverse proxy terminating ssl (cpu intensive), gzipping (cpu intensive) and doing other stuff + there are other servers doing cpu intensive work of main nodejs server, is it still wise to spawn as many workers as the number of cpu cores (for the main nodejs server)?
2. What tests should be run to find the optimal number of workers?

Comment: Since you've provided no quantitative data about what any of your processes need in terms of CPU at any particular load, there is no way to answer your questions without just devising a representative load test and running it with several different number of nodejs processes up to `numCPUs` and see which gives you the best overall throughput.  Even if you had some meaningful quantitative data, you would still probably need to run tests to verify your decisions.

Comment: A couple too many processes is probably less of a problem than not enough.  Not enough leaves you with idle CPUs and complete wasted capacity.  Too many processes just adds a few more context switches to swap CPU between them.

Comment: I've implemented this exact thing in the past in production using the information found in my answer. If you have any further questions let me know. It was downvoted by@jfriend00, but I can assure you this solution does work and is production strong.

Answer (score -3):

1. You can [set an affinity for the process to a set of cores](https://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset).
2. You should have one worker per core available core. By available core I mean a core that will not be heavily utilized by other processes.

To ensure everything is fine, your `(CPU load / number of cores)` should be below 1.

Try to provision your machines with very few distinct services/processes. This might seem wasteful at first but it helps MMTD and MMTR for incidents by limiting impact for cascading failures.

NOTE: this question is usually better asked at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: This does not seem to answer any of the questions the OP is asking.  Their question is specifically about the case where there are other processes running on the same host that make heavy use of the CPU.  The question is how to optimize total throughput, not only nodejs work.

Comment: I would recommend to have each node process in an exclusive core if possible.

Comment: The OP is asking how many nodejs processes to run in cluster form.  The OS will decide affinity.  When there are lots of other things happening on the server, you can't just give all CPU to nodejs.

Comment: By default the OS will decide affinity but you can [set an affinity manually](https://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset) as well. This is the meaning of my point #1. That's the set up we had at our company.

Comment: You are completely ignoring the main point of the question that there are several other processes on the same host doing CPU-intensive work.  You basically haven't answered any of that.  You have answered as if there is nothing else being done on the host except nodejs.  That is not the case here.

Comment: I disagree. I've implemented this verbatim solution in production and guaranteed provisioning for 3 services, each one running with affinity set to different cores in an 8 cores box.

Comment: And, do you have the exact same situation as in the question?  With multiple other CPU-intensive processes?  And, did you test to see that your solution is actually optimal with the same situation as the OP?  It sounds like you're just spouting the usual one process per CPU without taking into account any of the other factors cited in the question.  And, you haven't addressed the OP's point number 2 either.  This just isn't an answer to the specific question asked.  It's just a repeat of the generic advice which the OP already knows about.

Comment: Let the OP decide that. I had the same problem as OP and I solved it for a large production deployment in this way. You seem to be making many assumptions here. Also try a less confrontational tone. Then, I did address point #2, on my point #2.

Comment: @arboreal84 - did you try running your application without setting affinity of a process to a cpu core? Was the result worse than when affinity was set? (Is it possible for you to run this experiment?)

Comment: I do not feel the need to prove well documented behavior (processor affinity, and multitasking). If you are skeptical you can create a simple program that uses 100% CPU for one core (e.g: an infinite loop), run it along your server and then hit your local server with a load test client such as ApacheBench. Then play with the affinity. Meanwhile ApacheBench will give you stats on the server.